# Comparison Macro

Tags: excel, comparison, vba

I have a macro that does the following:

**SETUP:**

1. Compares a ID# between the "April Count" and "Prg-Srv Data" and turns the ones that are in common to a green cell background.
2. Filters the common data (anything with a green cell background) and copies that to a new worksheet "Medicaid Report". Then clears the AutoFilter and and formats the worksheet to specified style.
3. Filters and removes any rows that contain the word "Duplicate".
4. Finally it compares the April Count to the Medicaid Report to see if anyone has been missed from the April Count list.

**PROBLEM IS THIS:**

When the macro is finished it is still "randomly" marking data in the April Count that is also in the Medicaid Report and I'm not sure what I have done wrong.

*Also if there is a more efficient way to do this let me know, this macro takes a long time to run and I'm not sure if its just because it has to do 5,000+ records or if I coded inefficiently.*  Thanks

**CODE:**

```
Sub ComparePrgSrv()
    'Get the last row
    Dim Report As Worksheet
    Dim Report2 As Worksheet
    Dim Report3 As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim LastRow, LastRow2, LastRow3 As Integer
    Dim UniqueVal As New Collection
    Dim Val As String

    Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("April Count")
    Set Report2 = Excel.Worksheets("Prg-Srv Data")
    Set Report3 = Excel.Worksheets("Medicaid Report")

    LastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.count
    LastRow2 = Report2.UsedRange.Rows.count
    LastRow3 = Report3.UsedRange.Rows.count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'April Count to Program Services comparison.
    For i = 2 To LastRow2
        For j = 2 To LastRow
            If Report2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
                If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 1).Value, Report2.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Report2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 51) 'Dark green background
                    Report2.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 204, 102) 'Light green font color
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Report2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                    Report2.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Filter Program Services to show correct data.
    Report2.Range("$A$1:$M$" & LastRow2).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(0, 102, 51), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

    'Copy filtered data to new worksheet.
    Report2.Range("$A$1:$M$" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Medicaid Report").Range("A1")

    'Clear filter selection on both sheets.
    Report.AutoFilterMode = False
    Report2.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Format cell colors on Medicaid sheet.
    Report3.UsedRange.Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
    Report3.UsedRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color

    Report3.Range("$A$1:$M$1").Interior.Color = RGB(31, 73, 125) 'Blue background
    Report3.Range("$A$1:$M$1").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White font color

    'Filter and Delete Rows Containing "DUPLICATE"
    With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "*DUPLICATE*"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    'April Count to Medicaid Report comparison.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        For j = 2 To LastRow3
            If Report.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
                If InStr(1, Report3.Cells(j, 1).Value, Report.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Workbook Setup:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, what do you mean by

> "When the macro is finished "

For the effectiveness part:
You should remove the `If Report2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then` as it is already taken in account with the `InStr`.  If cell is empty `InStr` will evaluate as 0; that should speed up a bit.

Secondly, you should get the last row of data using this:

```
LastRow = Report.Range("a" & Report.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Report2.Range("a" & Report2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow3 = Report3.Range("a" & Report3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

"a" being the column containing the data to be checked.  This will give you exactly the last non-empty row of the aimed column instead of the total used range of the entire sheet.

Also, in VBA, when you declare variables on one line, this:
`Dim i, j, k As Integer`
will only declare "k" as an `Integer` but "i" and "j" will be `Variant`

You should write it as:
`Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer`.  Same remark for `Dim LastRow, LastRow2, LastRow3 As Integer`

And don't forget to enable the `Application.ScreenUpdating` before exiting the `Sub`.

Comment: ..."when the macro is finished" just means that after it runs and has completed the comparisons the compared data has errors in it.

Example: Jacobson has been marked red (left out) of the Medicaid report however you can see on the right sheet that she is in the Medicaid Report.

I am trying to understand my error in comparison when I thought I was comparing ID Numbers.

Comment: Honestly, I really don't see where the bug is, it should work.  I also tried comparing one number as number against another number as text and it worked.  Find something else for the effectiveness though.  In the `For j = 2` you could replace the "2" by a variable that is the last row checked in the `For` loop.  So instead of restarting each time from the top, you'd start where you left.

Comment: ...what should my code look like if I wanted to compare the "Medicaid Report" NCWISEID to the "April Count" USID column?  Both are column "A" on their respective sheets. The code is not highlighting ID numbers that aren't on the Medicaid Report but are on the April Count

Comment: If you try:`If InStr(1, Trim(Report.Cells(j, 1).Value), Trim(Report2.Cells(i, 1).Value), vbTextCompare) Then`does it work?

Comment: No that did not work... the ID numbers are identical in form. It just isn't picking up the fact that "318056" is not being highlighted on the April Count sheet when that ID Number doesn't appear on the Medicaid Report.